# Prevent "System.Windows.Controls.Label: value" being stored

Tags: c#, wpf

I've run into a small issue trying to save data from a label. The value from the label is stored in a string variable however for some reason I get the text mentioned in the title stored as well as in the value in the variable.

My current code looks something like this:

```
    string tempValue = lblPerson.ToString()
```

Any idea how to prevent "System.Windows.Controls.Label" being added to my variable?

Comment: Use the WPF tag instead of putting that information in the title.

Comment: @LarsTech any idea what the WPF tag is?

Comment: Those grey looking buttons underneath your question.  People who look for WPF questions would be filtering the front page list for those, so your question would get their attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My appologies, didn't see the WPF tag.

[Label Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label?view=netframework-4.7.2)

string tempValue = lblPerson.Content;